# Python: is there a way to "secretly" put text into a string?

Tags: python

I have been programming for about 2 months so I am relatively new to Python and programming in general.

I have a class with a field that will contain strings.  I am trying to find a way to denote this string so that I can call it, but I don't want it to print the denotation.  Is there a way to have a string contain text that won't be displayed when it is printed?  This is what I mean by "secretly."  I know I could make a separate field for this, and there are more complex ways to get around this, but I am wondering if the simple, easy process I am describing is possible.

So my use for this would be along the lines of:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

x = A('\\magical marker\\this is a string.')
y = A("\\other magical marker\\this is a different string")

something = x # I am going to have a variable that could be many different things

if something.message.startswith('\\magical marker\\'):
    print something
else: 
    pass
```

but when I print `something`, I want it to come out like this:

```
this is my string
```

sans the magical marker.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If this existed, it would be substantially less simple and easy than you expect.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to have these secret strings for?

Comment: Wusji, It's a little too convoluted to explain in a comment, but basically I am making a Pokemon style game and am trying to distinguish whether an attack is a stat booster for the user or a stat reducer for the enemy.  I am trying to customize the message printed to the user using `.format()`. In any case, this question was just a hypothetical and the solution isn't critical to the making of my game.

Comment: Then it'd be much simpler to just do something like `x = A(message = 'this is a string', stat_booster = True)`.

Comment: In summation, this is not a simple, easy process.  That's all I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

You print `something`, which happens to be an instance of `A`. So you can define what happens when you try to print an object by defining a magic method [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__):

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self, message):
   ...:         self.message = message
   ...:     
   ...:     def __str__(self):
   ...:         return self.message.split('}', 1)[-1]
   ...:     

In [2]: x = A('{marker}my message')

In [3]: print(x)
my message
```

Note that printing `x.message` will print the whole string:

```
In [4]: x.message
Out[4]: '{marker}my message'
```

Changing that would be quite confusing.

Comment: This is correct, but probably not too useful.  It won't handle the conditional, for example.  That could be added somehow but at what cost?  I think what the OP is trying to do is just a bad idea.

Comment: You would need maxsplit=1 to avoid the wrong output if there were a } elsewhere in the string.

Comment: @5gon12eder Maybe the conditional could be put in the `__str__` if needed, but without a more thorough description by the OP, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I think the more robust (and efficient) solution would be to add a boolean attribute to the class.  Then you can write `if x.should_print: print x;` and you don't need to mess with the string content.  But the OP didn't seem to want this obvious solution for some reason I cannot understand.

Comment: I did state in the question that I knew there were ways of getting around this.  My purpose in asking this was to determine whether I could essentially use an unprinted "variable" within a string that wouldn't be printed when the string was printed.  It's not a problem I need solved, it is simply an exploration of Python's capabilities, me being a new user.

Answer (score 2):

How about re-programming the dot operator using properties.

```
class A(str):

    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    @property
    def message(self):
        return 'this is my string'

    @message.setter
    def message(self, value):
        self._message = value


x = A('\\magical marker\\this is a string.')
y = A("\\other magical marker\\this is a different string")

something = x
print x.message
```

This will always print 'this is my string' when you try to access the message field.

Answer (score 1):

If you inherit from `str` you can simply str.replace:

```
class A(str):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

x = A('\\magical marker\\this is a string.')
y = A("\\other magical marker\\this is a different string")

something = x # I am going to have a variable that could be many different things

if something.message.startswith('\\magical marker\\'):
    print something.replace('\\magical marker\\',"",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dirty little hack would be to use strings vs unicode strings:

```
x = 'this is a string.'
y = u'this is a unicode string.'

if isinstance(something, str):
    print 'str'
else:
    print 'unicode'
```

That only gets you two different classes, though. Maybe that's all you need?

Comment: This is quite "dirty" as you say and it does fit my application.  It is a solution proportional to the amount of work I want to do, though certainly not as broad in its range of use.

Comment: Certainly. I just like that it's as easy as adding a `u`.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have clever ideas that reveal interesting parts of Python... but miss the mark on matching your code to your goals, in a minimal and idiomatic way.

It sounds like the 'marker' is extra state that you want to remember and have affect later decisions.

So best would be to make that explicit: change your `A` class to accept another (probably optional) initialization argument:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, message, marker=None):
        self.message = message
        self.marker = marker
```

Then you later check the marker value directly and explicitly, without any 'hiding' or 'unpacking':

```
x = A('this is a string', marker='magic1')

if x.marker == 'magic1':
    print x.message
else: 
    pass
```

This better describes the multifaceted nature of your `A` objects – even if their main purpose is carrying a string `message`, they've got other significant state, and it's good to give that state a distinctive name and place. You don't have to 'hide' it inside the main message – just give it its own slot.

(You might even move the conditional-logic, that determines what/whether to print, into another descriptively-named method on the `A` class – making instances of `A` responsible for their own display-rules.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this.

```
class SecretText(str):

    def __str__(self):
        """Return empty string."""
        return ''

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return empty string."""
        return self.__str__()

class SomewhatSecretText(str):

    def __init__(self, *text):
        """Initialize a SomewhatSecretText instance."""
        self.items = list(text)
        assert self.verify_types()
        # We have to keep some trace. Or we will
        # never be able to get the original value.
        self.message = ''.join(self.items)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return string with hidden text."""
        vis = ""
        for item in self.items:
            vis += str(item)
        return vis

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return string with hidden text."""
        return self.__str__()

    def __dir__(self):
        """
        This is so self.message and self.items aren't
        visible when dir() is called on the instance.
        """
        return dir(str)

    def verify_types(self):
        """Confirm instance items are strings."""
        for item in self.items:
            if not isinstance(item, str):
                return False
        return True
```

Using `SomewhatSecretText`, you can implement hidden text. Like this:

```
>>> hidden = SecretText("test")
>>> partly_hidden = SomewhatSecretText("This is a ", hidden, "!")
>>> print(partly_hidden)
This is a !
>>> print(repr(partly_hidden))
This is a !
>>> print(str(partly_hidden))
This is a !
```

You can get the full text back using the `message` variable.

```
>>> print(partly_hidden)
This is a !
>>> print(partly_hidden.message)
This is a test!
```

A bonus is that you can submit any number of strings to tag together. So you could have multiple hidden pieces.